# Is there a way to ask RubyGems' `gem` command what version of a gem it could and would install?

Tags: rubygems

I would like to know what version of a given gem **would** be installed if I asked for it to be installed. For instance, (at the time of this writing) if I execute `gem install rails` it will install `4.0.0`. But I would prefer to just ask `gem` rather than have to go to https://rubygems.org/gems/rails

Example:

```
-bash> gem info rails -v
4.0.0
```

Also, I want to know what versions it **could** install. Again, instead of having to go to RubyGems -- https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions -- I just want to ask `gem` for the last `10` versions:

```
-bash> gem info rails -v 10
4.0.1.rc1 October 17, 2013 (1.48 MB)
4.0.0 June 25, 2013 (1.47 MB)
4.0.0.rc2 June 11, 2013 (1.47 MB)
4.0.0.rc1 April 29, 2013 (1.49 MB)
4.0.0.beta1 February 26, 2013 (1.49 MB)
3.2.15 October 16, 2013 (4.5 KB)
3.2.15.rc3 October 11, 2013 (4.5 KB)
3.2.15.rc2 October 4, 2013 (4.5 KB)
3.2.15.rc1 October 3, 2013 (4.5 KB)
3.2.14 July 22, 2013 (3.5 KB)
```

Does a CLI for something like this exist in `gem`?

Incidentally, it would be cool if without `-v` it would tell me the equivalent of what the RubyGems web page tells me:

```
-bash> gem info rails
About: Ruby on Rails is a full-stack web framework optimized for programmer 
       happiness and sustainable productivity. It encourages beautiful code
       by favoring convention over configuration.

Author: David Heinemeier Hansson

Version: 4.0.0
Total downloads: 28,483,741
For this version: 801,825

License: MIT

RubyGems:      https://rubygems.org/gems/rails
Homepage:      http://www.rubyonrails.org/
Source Code:   http://github.com/rails/rails
Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/
Wiki:          http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/
Mailing List:  http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk
Bug Tracker:   http://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Gemfile:
    gem "rails", "~> 4.0.0"

Versions:
    4.0.1.rc1 October 17, 2013 (1.48 MB)
    3.2.15 October 16, 2013 (4.5 KB)
    3.2.15.rc3 October 11, 2013 (4.5 KB)
    3.2.15.rc2 October 4, 2013 (4.5 KB)
    3.2.15.rc1 October 3, 2013 (4.5 KB)
    https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions

Runtime Dependencies:
    actionmailer = 4.0.0
    actionpack = 4.0.0
    activerecord = 4.0.0
    activesupport = 4.0.0
    bundler < 2.0, >= 1.3.0
    railties = 4.0.0
    sprockets-rails ~> 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find which version "would" be installed with remote:

```
gem query --remote -n^rails$ #the -n parameter takes a regex
```

Alternately,

```
gem search ^rails$
```

(I don't think there's a big difference between these two commands other than the argument style, but query defaults to local, and search defaults to remote)

If you want to know which versions are available, you can do:

```
gem search --all ^rails$ #defaults to remote
gem query -n^rails$ #defaults to local
```

If you want Author/Homepage/License information, you can add the --details flag. It doesn't appear that all of the information is available unless you have it locally.

If you don't mind the information about licensing, homepage, and so on being in Yaml, you can use:

```
gem specification --remote rails
```

It will show the homepage, current version, authors, date, and dependency information. (It defaults to locally installed gems).